# Select labels for plotting a bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have an excel file that contains information about some data with two columns, one describing the object and one how many that object appears, for example:

```
house     5
car       3
boat      2
```

I want to create an histogram, so I created a pandas df

```
X = pandas.read_table("myfile.txt")   
categories = pandas.DataFrame({
    "object": X["object"],
    "total": X["total"]
})
```

Next I plot it by:

```
categories.total.to_frame("objects").query("objects> 2").sort_values("objects", ascending=False).plot.bar(width=1)
```

This works, but I would like to show, on the x axis, the name of the objects, right now it just enumerates the objects. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas uses index per default when plotting x-axis, so you can easily set it:

```
In [27]: categories.set_index('object').query("total > 2").sort_values('total', ascending=False).plot.bar(rot=0, width=1)
Out[27]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xabace48>
```

[image]

alternatively you can specify x axis explicitly:

```
In [31]: categories.query("total > 2").sort_values('total', ascending=False).plot.bar(x='object', rot=0, width=1)
Out[31]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xa9a64e0>
```

Comment: Is x='object' the correct syntax? The first example works, but the second one does not, it gives me an error: KeyError: 'object'

Comment: That is strange, because option1 works fine, so that cannot be the reason.